# The product of two non-zero formal power series is non-zero

Tags: linear-algebra

If $F$ is a field, show that the product of any two non-zero elements of $F^{\infty}$ in non-zero. (Exercise 5 on page 123 of Linear Algebra by Hoffman)

I tried to prove the statement in this way:
Let $f$ and $g$ we any two non-zero elements in $F^{\infty}$.

Case 1
If $fg$ has infinitely many non-zero terms, then there is nothing left to prove.

Case 2
$fg$ has finitely many terms that are non-zero.
We may let N be the maximum index such that $$(fg)_{k} \ne 0$$.
In other words, $(fg)_k =0$ for all $k>N$.

From here I don't know how to proceed. It seems that both $f$ and $g$ should have finite degrees but I don't know how to argue.

Any help will be  much appreciated!

Thanks!

Best regards,
Michael.

Comment: What is $F^\infty$?

Comment: Let $f_i,g_j$ be the least non-zero terms in $f,g$.    Then the coefficient of $x^{i+j}$ is the product $f_i\times g_j$ and is non-zero

Comment: in general the space of formal power series is defined by the notation $\Bbb F[\![X]\!]$.

Comment: Thanks! I got your proof.  Another question:
Is it possible that both $f$ and $g$ have infinitely many non-zero terms but yet $fg$ has finitely many non-zero terms? It is intuitively correct but I don't know how to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f,g\in F^{\infty}.$ Then $f=(f_0,f_1,\dots)$ and $g=(g_0,g_1,\dots)$

Choose the smallest $p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_p\ne 0$ and smallest $q\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g_q\ne 0.$

Then

$$(fg)_{p+q}=\sum_{i=0}^{p+q}f_ig_{p+q-i}=\begin{cases}f_pg_q,\text{if } p<q\\f_qg_p, \text{if }q<p\end{cases}$$

which is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the lexicographic monomial order, for example, in case your power series are in several variables.

Let $a$ be the non-zero term of smallest degree of $f$ and $b$ that of $g$ then $ab$ is the term of smallest degree of $fg$ and it is non-zero.